# Icons on ToolBar Not Responding When Navigation Drawer Added

Tags: android

I added a Navigation Drawer to my Activity and it seems to be working fine. The problem is that I have another icon on my Toolbar called info, which is now not responding. This info item exists in my menu.xml file:

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:title="Info"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

I inflate this menu in my Java code:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_items, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And add it to my onOptionsItemsSelectedMethod, which also contains my navigation drawer:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.home:{
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList)){
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
            }else{
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerList);
            }
            return true;
        }case R.id.info:{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"HEY",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        default:return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The icon pops up on my ToolBar but does not respond when I click on it. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs need to be kept consistent

in **xml** you have :

```
android:id="@+id/infoActionBar"
```

in **java** code, you are looking for :

```
case R.id.info:
```

Change either of those, to match with the other one.

**Edit:**
Replace `case R.id.home:` with `case android.R.id.home:`

Comment: Just changed it. Still nothing

Comment: @MarkF I used all three snippets of your code in a project, and the toast was shown correctly. Might need more information to solve your issue.
Also, you might want to replace `case R.id.home:` with `case android.R.id.home:`

Comment: Yes, that's it. The case wasn't being used. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkF I updated the answer accordingly, you can choose it as the correct answer if it solved the issue for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your info button id in your xml is  `android:id="@+id/infoActionBar"` and you try to call `case R.id.info:` so please change one of them and try again :)

`infoActionBar` **vs** `info`

Answer (score 0):

In `onOptionsItemSelected`it must be id of the item not the title in case of `item.getItemId()`

```
@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.home:{
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList)){ 
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList); 
            }else{ 
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerList); 
            } 
            return true; 
        }case R.id.infoActionBar:{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"HEY",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
        default:return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } 
}
```